# JConsole can't find process

Tags: jconsole

I tried to run JConsole to analyze the memory used by a running process, but JConsole doesn't show me processes even though I am absolutely sure that one is running (in addition to that it should show JConsole in the process list as well but it doesn't).

Does anyone have an idea why it doesn't show any processes?

Cheers

Answer (score 17):

at window prompt, run echo %TMP%, it will give you default temp dir. Go to that directory and find  directory named hsperfdata_*user* where *user* is your login. This is directory to store your process id. Any new process you created such as java application will have a new file named by process id. Jconsole will pick up the process ids from this directory. If you cannot create a file in this directory, that means you need change permission to allow write. Once done that, start a new java application to see if new process id file is in the dir. Once confirmed, start jconsole

Comment: If the java process is started from cygwin it will have a different TEMP folder than expected - jconsole, started from explorer wont find the process then.

Comment: Thanks James! Fixing the permissions worked for me! :)

Comment: from cygwin prompt, needed to `export TMP=/cygdrive/C/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp`

Comment: In most cases, running JConsole as an Administrator will do the trick

Comment: This answer helped me with VisualVM too. So anyone who has the problem of not showing your local process in Visualvm's application list also should try this.

Answer (score 14):

I have the same problem.  But if I explicitly specify the PID, as in `jconsole 1234`, jconsole is able to analyze the process.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you do this?

Comment: @SteveWestbrook, Open a terminal, and instead of running "jconsole", run "jconsole 1234" where 1234 is the PID of your Java process. Now as to how to find the PID of your Java process, you can do it via Task Manager in Windows or by running "ps ax" in Linux..

Answer (score 9):

If you are running jconsole on windows - simply :

1. Find **jconsole.exe**
2. Right click it
3. Select **run as administrator**.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, removal of `hsperfdata_USERNAME` directory (in `%TMP%` directory) and closing all the JVMs has helped.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when %TMP% value is different for monitored JVM and the monitoring tool (JConsole/JMC/Java Mission Control, maybe even VisualVM).
This may be the standard scenario with Cygwin (at least in my case: Cygwin+Babun)
Easiest solution is to set value of the TMP environment variable to the default value used by Windows, at least in scope of shell launching the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

You have to start jconsole with the same user as the process you want to analyze is started by.

Comment: Even i am running from same user still i am not able to run jconsole.

Comment: Tried this, jconsole is still not seeing my process

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this issue

If you are using multiple jdk's by any chance (ex. SDKMAN), then make sure that `jconsole` is run using the same jdk as the application

Answer (score 1):

8 years later... I had the same problem. I could only see certain processes but couldn't see and monitor any java processes running in a docker container in Linux.

Inspired by [the Windows solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48099377/4739826) by RoyalBigMack:

- Solution 1. Run terminal as super user (`su` command) and run `jconsole`
- Solution 2. Run solution 1 as one command, `sudo jconsole`

Only the first solution worked for me, and once the jconsole UI popped up- all the hidden processes were now visible.