# Why JConsole can't lunch or start

Tags: java, memory-management, jconsole, resource-monitor

I am facing issue here JConsole is not running.

Even though in my system  `hsperfdata_USERNAME` directory and pid file also created. After that I try to run jconsole from the command line neither it  shows any error nor i am seeing jconsole is running .

Today I have install JdK9 and I am facing this issue. 
Please refer below image, thanks in advance for any kind of information or help.

I have refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746640/jconsole-cant-find-process/46509834?noredirect=1#comment79978500_46509834) and tried but still i could not start Jconsole.

[image]

Comment: Don't you get any error message in a separate window?

Comment: I did not get any error I use Java Mission Control, 
But i could not understand why my Jconsole is not getting start in my Jdk9.

But when I run JDK 8 its  run fine. 

Seems some problem is there with JDK 9 and JConsole.

Comment: Are you using the JConsole-binary from the same JDK you want to monitor? This has been an issue in the past - at times even when using different patch-levels. Please check you are not executing your application via a jre unrelated to the jdk, your JConsole binary comes from

Comment: Another issue, we have stumbled across is that the mechanism to attach to locally running processes via JConsole or JVisualVM parses directories case sensitive even in windows. This can be an issue, when you are using windows in a AD-Setting and, at the same time, have a local account with the same name but with a upper/lowercase mixup.

Comment: Did you noticed any case sensitive issue in my console screen. may be it was not the that particular issue.
Somethings else might causing problem